# How to add custom static code analysis rules in Visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static-analysis

I am using Visual studio Professional 2015 for my C++ program on Windows. I tried to add my own static code analysis rules to the static analysis rules set. But it dint work. 
I can only edit the rule set into custom rule set.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264974.aspx
I could not find any guidance on how to add my own rules to this. 
I found this method of adding rules but it is for Visual Studio 2010. I believe the methodology is simpler for Visual Studio 2015.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: My knowledge may be outdated, but it is my understanding that you cannot write custom rules for C++.